# Do Java Sets accept duplicate String[]?

Tags: java, android, set

In my Android app, I use a query to get all contacts in the phone. I know that this may lead to duplicate elements so I use a `LinkedHashSet` to handle it:

```
private void retrieveContacts(ContentResolver contentResolver) {
    LinkedHashSet<String[]> contactSet = new LinkedHashSet<String[]>();
    final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER }, null,
            null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    if (cursor == null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst() == true) {
        do {
            final String name = cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            final String telephone = cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).replace(" ", "").replace("+336", "06");
            String[] contactString = {telephone, name};
            contactSet.add(contactString);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext() == true);
    }

    if (cursor.isClosed() == false) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    for (String[] contactString : contactSet){
        Contact contact = new Contact(contactString[0], contactString[1], false, false);
        daocontact.add(contact);
    }
```

`Contact` is a Bean I use which represents a contact, and daocontact is a DAO which stores the contact in a database. The problem is, it seems the Set actually stores duplicate elements because when I display a ListView based on the records of my database, it shows me lots of duplicate elements.

Why does the `Set` accept duplicate elements? How to fix this?

Comment: "Why does the Set accept duplicate elements?" -- they are not duplicates. They are independent objects. "How to fix this?" -- write your own Java class that holds onto two `String` objects as data members, and implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` as you see fit on that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `LinkedHashSet<String[]>` is not a good idea as a `LinkedHashSet` checks for duplicates by calling `equals`, whereas `equals()` for `String[]` just uses `==`. This means that `new String[] {"12345", "Joe"}` and `new String[] {"12345", "Joe"}` are not considered equal.

Instead you should define a class called `Contact` as follows:

```
public final class Contact {

    private final String number;
    private final String name;

    public Contact(String number, String name) {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String number() { return number; }

    public String name() { return name; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == this)
            return true;
        if (!(object instanceof Contact))
            return false;
        Contact that = (Contact) object;
        return that.number.equals(number) && that.name.equals(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return number.hashCode() ^ name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to use a `LinkedHashSet<Contact>`.

Comment: This solution works and enables me to manipulate my Contact Bean direclty in the Set. Thank you

Comment: @Kritias Be **very careful**. I deliberately didn't give `Contact` `setName` or `setNumber` methods. If you change `name` or `number`, the `hashCode` will change, and you will no longer be able to find the `Contact` in the `Set`.

Comment: thank you for warning me about that, I will be careful.

Answer (score 2):

String[] doesn't have the `hashCode()` and `equals` semantics that `LinkedHashSet` expects to maintain uniqueness.

For a quick fix, try using `ArrayList<String>` instead of `String[]`, which does define these methods.

EDIT - you can simplify iterating over cursor results by using the following idiom instead of `moveToFirst`:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
  // .. use the cursor
}
```

This works because cursor semantics guarantee that the cursor will be placed right before the first result, if any, and will return false if there's no next value to row to move to.

Comment: This solution works perfectly but I prefer the one of pbabcdefp.

Comment: @Kritias fair enough, I like that solution too :)